# Has anyone successfully compiled a python 3 Kivy app?

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, kivy-language

Has anyone successfully compiled a python 3 Kivy app? If so please suggest some guidelines. We have developed a python 3/kivy app and wondered if it is worth the time/effort into producing an apk out of the application or is it even possible.

Thanks All

Comment: definitly possible, just follow the instructions with buildozer, see kivy website

Comment: My team has developed an app but cant seem to get the compilation environment correct. we have tried multiple times using the information provided on buildozer site. I have heard of building some apks with kivy. I have yet to see a robust app. People have pushed out simple apk Hello World.... I have yet to see a python 3 apk. If there is one please point my team in the direction so that we can obtain the information to build out our apk. I posted this after months of trying to get multiple environments setup for compilation.